# Google Big Query - How to get Last Updated Dates of all tables in a Dataset using SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

In a Google Big Query, I need to extract the last update dates of all tables in a given Dataset.  So the output I need is `<<TableName>>   <<Last Update Date>>`

I know how to list tables:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  table_id,
  row_count
FROM `myproject.mydataset.__TABLES__`
WHERE table_id IN ('TABLEA', 'TABLEB', 'TABLEC')
```

How do I get the last update date instead of row_count?

Thanks

Comment: is there a way to do it in the command line? or python?  I need to make a report of table status to show when they were last updated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below
If I correctly understood the question  - it has what you asked and many more

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT table_id,
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time)) AS creation_date,
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time)) AS last_modified_date,
    row_count,
    size_bytes,
    CASE
        WHEN type = 1 THEN 'table'
        WHEN type = 2 THEN 'view'
        WHEN type = 3 THEN 'external'
        ELSE '?'
    END AS type,
    TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time,
    TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time,
    dataset_id,
    project_id
FROM `myproject.mydataset.__TABLES__`
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my misinformation :) We need an example over `__TABLES__` in the docs...I'm only seeing the schema for `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` in the [meta tables topic](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#tables-meta-table).

Comment: make sense. I haven't even noticed that it is not covered in docs

Comment: This was an awesome to find out details about which tables weren't being updated:
just add a :
ORDER BY last_modified_date DESC

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that row_count and size_bytes does not work with tables binded with Google spreadsheets, they are both at 0.